# Не работает команда git switch

Tags: git, git-branch

При попытке переключиться между ветками при помощи git switch выдает ошибку:  cannot handle switch as a builtin.
Кто-то сталкивался? Через checkout все работает

Comment: Проверить версию `git`. Команда `switch` относительно недавно появилась.

Comment: Да, так и есть, была старая версия. Спасибо